# Problems with table display:block with image

Tags: html, css, image, css-tables

I'm trying to put some text next to an image on my homepage. Because I want my homepage to be responsive I used a table to do this, with this CSS:

```
    #tablehomepage {
    display: table;
}

#tablehomepage img {
    min-width: 280px;
    min-height: 190px;
}

#tablehomepage body {
    vertical-align: top;
}


@media (max-width: 920px) {
    #tablehomepage td {
        display: block;
    }
```

Complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/h3jhgns4/1/ . Weirdly the problem doesn't occur here...

My image is in the first cell, the text is in my second cell. There is only 1 row.

Some problems I currently have:

1. when the screen gets below 920 the 'display:block' kicks in, but puts my text around my image. I want to have the text below the image on smaller screens.
2. when the 'display:block' kicks in, some extra random border appears underneath my top border.
3. I cannot get the image to auto-scale to nicely fit next to the text on different screensizes. I guess this can be achieved by setting a static size for that cell and putting the image into the css as background, but then I cannot set alt-text (SEO is very important for me).

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/h3jhgns4/1/

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear. Your question should contain a complete code example. As an optional second step you can create a third-party example like jsFiddle.

Comment: added a link to jsfiddle with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the display to `inline-block` and for the text, add the `clear:booth` so it will need full row width, and it will not be around your image.